# Ничего не происходит при записи в БД Oracle с помощью EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Изучаю EF6 на БД Oracle 11g2 создал класс Test

```
class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public float T1 { get; set; }

    public float T2 { get; set; }

    public float T3 { get; set; }

    public float T4 { get; set; }

    public float T5 { get; set; }

    public float T6 { get; set; }

    public float T7 { get; set; }

    public float T8 { get; set; }

    public float T9 { get; set; }
}
```

Затем Context:

```
 internal class TestContext : DbContext
 {

    public virtual DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       // modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("USER");  
        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().ToTable("TESTI", "USER");
        Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new 
        CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TestContext>());
        //Database.SetInitializer< TestContext > (null);
    }      
}
```

Далее к кнопке привязал код записи:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          using (var db = new TestContext())
          {
            var test = new Test {Id = 1, T1 = 12, T2 = 3, T3 = 3, T4 = 3, T5 
                     = 3, T6 = 3, T7 = 3, T8 = 3 };
            db.Test.Add(test);
            db.SaveChanges();
          }
        }
```

При нажатии на кноку ничего не происходит. Я тогда пошел другим путём добавил еще 1 поле T9 в коде оно в незакомментированом виде, запустив кода я получил ошибку о том что нужно  произвести миграцию, окей приступаю, написав в консоле диспетчера пакетов несколько строк **Enable-Migrations**, **Add-Migration TEST**, **Update-Database**. Запускаю приложение жму кнопку и снова ничего в БД не появляется не таблицы не столбцов. Окей думаю создам таблицу вручную создав таблицу с полями запускаю приложение жму кнопку и снова ничего, так вот собственно вопрос, что же я не так делаю ? Куда улетают данные ? Почему нет не единой ошибки не единого исключения ? Помогите пожалуйста кто знает или сталкивался с подобным явлением.

Comment: чтобы это понять, вам надо поглядеть строку подключения, которую вы используете.

Comment: @tym32167 Что я там должен увидеть ? Связь с БД есть. Ибо если бы её небыло была бы ошибка TNS Connection

Comment: по идее, вы там должны увидеть факт, что вы подключаетесь к одной базе, а проверяете результаты в другой. Другого объяснения того, что вы накатили миграции БД без ошибок, но не увидели эти изменения/миграции в базе, у меня нет.

Comment: @tym32167 У меня нет в использовании 10 БД. Есть одна к которой я конечусь, если мы говорим конечно за БД а не за схемы. Если же мы говорим за схемы, то выше я явно указал **modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().ToTable("TESTI", "USER");** к какой схеме и какой таблице производить запись. Ну и третий вариант я не совсем понял что именно вы пытаетесь мне сказать.

Comment: я без понятия сколько у вас БД, но вы говорите, что вы сделали миграцию и успешно её накатили на базу (в случае неуспеха вот это `Update-Database` выдает ошибку). И после этого вы в БД не видите изменений. Таким образом, либо вы накатили изменения на какую то другую БД, либо команда `Update-Database` не рабочая. Но так как я когда то сам накатывал изменения с помощью `Update-Database`, то скорее всего вы что то путаете с базами и схемами. Вместо того, чтобы со мной тут спорить и тратить время зря, будьте так добры, найдите место, куда накатились ваши миграции.

Comment: @tym32167 Я прошерстил всю базу, все схемы, просмотрел все созданные талицы, но я в упор не вижу таблицы **TESTI** хотя я уже стал получать сообщение об ошибки ```There is already an object named 'TESTI' in the database.``` Которая явно говорит что такое имя существует в моей БД.

Comment: поглядите на ваши строки соединения в конфигах, может они вам подскажут, куда вы подключаетесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том, что была пропущена строка отвечающая за определение к какой БД подключится из App.config, а именно в класее **TestContext** нужно добавать сл. строчку:

```
 internal class TestContext : DbContext
 {
   public TestContext() : base("OracleDbContext"){ } // Пропущенная строка !

    public virtual DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       // modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("USER");  
        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().ToTable("TESTI", "USER");
        Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new 
        CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TestContext>());
        //Database.SetInitializer< TestContext > (null);
    }      
}
```